# Cloud Function is not running - React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

I'm new to React Native and I have an issue with Cloud Functions.

```
getAuthor(uid){
      var getUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getUser');
      console.log('success');
      getUser({uid: uid}).then(function(result) {
        console.log('getUser called')
        var user = result.data.uid;
        return(
          result
          )

      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        var code = error.code;
        var message = error.message;
        var details = error.details;
      });
    }
```

When I run this code, 'success' is printed but 'getUser called' is never printed. I take this to mean getUser is never called. But I have followed the Firebase guide 'Call functions from your app' and it seems to be the same. Is it a problem with Cloud Functions never being initialised or something? In the Firebase guide it says to initialise an instance of Cloud Functions by adding 
`var functions = firebase.functions();`
but when I added it to config.js I got an error so I skipped this step. Sorry if this seems obvious, I have never used React Native or Firebase before. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: the function has been deployed, as can be seen in this screenshot
[image]

This is the function, by the way:

```
exports.getUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const uid = data.uid;
        auth.getUser(uid)
        .then(function(UserRecord) {
            console.log('USER RECEIVED:' + UserRecord.email.toJSON());
            return {email : UserRecord.email.toJSON()};
          })
          .catch(function(error){
              console.log(error);
          });
```

Comment: Can you please post your code as text instead of an image? Thanks!

Comment: @norbitrial I've corrected it! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I can't access user information with their UID! The solution is to add it into Firebase Database instead.